# ERROR TypeError: a.markerClusterGroup is not a function

Tags: angular, leaflet, ngx-leaflet

I am currently using [asymmetrik's ngx-leaflet and ngx-leaflet-markercluster](https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet-markercluster/blob/master/README.md) with the following versions:

```
"@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet": "^5.0.2",
"@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet-markercluster": "^2.1.1"
```

During development everything is fine. However, when I build the angular project for production (`ng serve --prod`), I am not able to see the cluster markers and I get the following error in Chrome's console:

```
ERROR TypeError: a.markerClusterGroup is not a function
    at t.ngOnInit (main-es2015.94505399b2d83c23de95.js:1)
    at main-es2015.94505399b2d83c23de95.js:1
    at main-es2015.94505399b2d83c23de95.js:1
    at Kb (main-es2015.94505399b2d83c23de95.js:1)
    at xw (main-es2015.94505399b2d83c23de95.js:1)
    at Object.updateDirectives (14-es2015.a3c30690716486447af1.js:1)
    at Object.updateDirectives (main-es2015.94505399b2d83c23de95.js:1)
    at Xb (main-es2015.94505399b2d83c23de95.js:1)
    at rw (main-es2015.94505399b2d83c23de95.js:1)
    at nw (main-es2015.94505399b2d83c23de95.js:1)
```

I am importing 'leaflet' and 'leaflet.markercluster' in my component. Below is the **map.component.ts** code:

```
import { Component, Input, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { tileLayer, latLng, control, marker, divIcon, LatLngBounds, MarkerClusterGroup, MarkerClusterGroupOptions } from 'leaflet';

import { NgElement, WithProperties } from '@angular/elements';

import * as L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet.markercluster';
...

@Component({
    selector: 'map',
    styleUrls: ['./map.component.scss'],
    templateUrl: './map.component.html'
})
export class MapComponent {

    layers = [];
    markerClusterGroup: L.MarkerClusterGroup;
    markerClusterData: any[] = [];
    maxBounds: L.LatLngBounds;
    map: L.Map;

    options = {
        layers: [
            tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { maxZoom: 18 }),
        ],
        zoom: 2,
        zoomControl: false,
        maxZoom: 18
    };

    markerClusterOptions: L.MarkerClusterGroupOptions = {
        showCoverageOnHover: true,
        animate: true,
        chunkedLoading: true,
        zoomToBoundsOnClick: true,
        spiderfyOnMaxZoom: true,
        chunkDelay: 500,
        animateAddingMarkers: true,
        chunkInterval: 7,
        iconCreateFunction: function (cluster) {
            var markers = cluster.getAllChildMarkers();
            var icon = divIcon({
                iconSize: [35, 35],
                iconAnchor: [10, 10],
                popupAnchor: [10, 0],
                shadowSize: [0, 0],
                html: '<div>' + cluster.getChildCount() + '</div>'
            });

            if (markers.find(x => x.options.alt == enum.A)) {
                icon.options.className = 'cluster cluster-critical';
            } else if (markers.find(x => x.options.alt == enum.B)) {
                icon.options.className = 'cluster cluster-warning';
            } else {
                icon.options.className = 'cluster cluster-normal';
            }

            return icon;
        }
    };

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
        this.fixMap();
    }

    mapReady(map: L.Map) {
        this.map = map;
        map.addControl(control.zoom({ position: 'bottomright' }));
        this.fixMap();
    }

    fixMap() {
        if (this.map) {
            this.setBounds();
            this.map.fitBounds(this.maxBounds);
            this.initMarkers();
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.map.invalidateSize();
            }, 0);
        }
    }

    markerClusterReady(group: L.MarkerClusterGroup) {
        this.markerClusterGroup = group;
        this.markerClusterGroup.addLayers(this.markerClusterData);
    }

    initMarkers() {
        this.markerClusterData = [];
        this.objectList.forEach(x => {
            var location = latLng(x.location.latitude, x.location.longitude);
            var system = marker(location, {
                icon: divIcon({
                    iconSize: [30, 30],
                    iconAnchor: [10, 10],
                    popupAnchor: [10, 0],
                    shadowSize: [0, 0],
                    className: this.getMarkerStyle(x),
                }),
                title: x.serialNumber,
                alt: x.objectStatusSummary.status
            });

            system.bindPopup(fl => this.createPopupComponent(x), {
                className: 'popup',
                closeButton: false
            }).on('click', (data) => {
                this.focusOnMarker(x);
            });

            this.markerClusterData.push(system);
        });
    }

    focusOnMarker(object: Object) {
        var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds([[object.objectLocation.latitude, object.objectLocation.longitude]]);
        this.map.fitBounds(bounds, {
            animate: true,
            duration: 1,
            easeLinearity: 1,
            maxZoom: this.map.getZoom(),
            noMoveStart: true
        });
    }

    setBounds() {
        var latLngArray: any[] = [];
        if (this.objectList && this.objectList.length > 0) {
            this.objectList.forEach(x => {
                latLngArray.push({
                    lat: x.objectLocation.latitude,
                    lng: x.objectLocation.longitude,
                });
            });
        }
        else {
            latLngArray.push({
                lat: 0,
                lng: 0
            });
        }
        this.maxBounds = new L.LatLngBounds(latLngArray);
    }

    getMarkerStyle(object: object) {
        return 'marker marker-' + this.businessHelper.getClassByStatus(<objectHealthStatusEnum>object.objectStatusSummary.status) + ' marker-' + object.serialNumber;
    }

    resetZoom() {
        this.map.fitBounds(this.maxBounds, {
            animate: true,
            duration: 1,
            easeLinearity: 1,
            noMoveStart: true
        });
    }

    public createPopupComponent(object) {
        const popupEl: NgElement & WithProperties<MapPopupComponent> = document.createElement('popup-element') as any;
        popupEl.addEventListener('closed', () => document.body.removeChild(popupEl));
        popupEl.object = object;
        document.body.appendChild(popupEl);
        return popupEl;
    }
}
```

This is the **map.component.html** code:

```
<div class="map-wrapper">
    <div 
        leaflet 
        [leafletOptions]="options" 
        (leafletMapReady)="mapReady($event)"

        [leafletMarkerCluster]="markerClusterData"
        [leafletMarkerClusterOptions]="markerClusterOptions"
        (leafletMarkerClusterReady)="markerClusterReady($event)"
    ></div>
</div>
```

You can find the main code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sok9qy).

Any ideas?

Comment: try to serve in your local machine as `--prod` and see if the error occurs there too.

Comment: @EliyaCohen yes same error: 
leaflet_src.markerClusterGroup is not a function
at LeafletMarkerClusterDirective.ngOnInit...

Comment: Can  you show your code?

Comment: Added it to the question

Comment: Where is the function `markerClusterReady` getting called?

Comment: Added map.component.html as well.

Comment: Which versions of Leaflet and Leaflet.markercluster are you using? Since your issue happens only in production build, you should probably share your Angular configuration, and tsconfig. Providing a live reproduction (e.g. on StackBlitz) would also tremendously help.

Comment: I added the link to the code on StackBlitz (link in question). Not all the map tiles are showing too for some reason (thought it was an https problem).

Comment: @Nick why you have imported `leaflet` js files in index.html?

Comment: @Plochie I removed them from the code. Still same error.

Comment: @Nick did you resolve your issue? having the same problem

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same problem and found a solution. The problem is that there are different leaflets imported as 'L' from the definitions.
Make sure to import leaflet first, then the other packages, e.g.:

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import { Map, MapOptions, MarkerClusterGroup, MarkerClusterGroupOptions } from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet.markercluster';
```

another guess would be that the timing in production is different than on develop. your `initMarkers` gets called via `ngOnChanges` but that might be to early. The map or the cluster might not be initialized yet. Try to call `initMarkers` within `markerClusterReady` or `mapReady`

Answer (score 0):

Don't import leaflet through html, install the package and import the modules you need instead

Comment: I removed them and still doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Hello I had same issue in Angular project. I'm using NPMs.

```
npm i leaflet @types/leaflet
npm i leaflet.markercluster @types/leaflet.markercluster
npm i leaflet.fullscreen @types/leaflet.fullscreen
```

**Solution**: Import leaflet and its plugins in your `app.module.ts` file:

```
import 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet.markercluster';
import 'leaflet.fullscreen'
```

And also import these like this in your component where you use your map:

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet.markercluster';
import 'leaflet.fullscreen';
```

It is because of Lazy loading modules. Project will work on localhost, but build version won't. So you have to import like I said above.